# Constants of 128-bit key version of the stream cipher Chacha

Tags: stream-cipher, key-size

I am trying to find  constants of 128-bit key version of the stream cipher Chacha.

I know for 256-bit key version, constants are 0x61707865, 0x3320646e, 0x79622d32, 0x6b206574.

Are these same for both versions?